# Kiosk with camera Internet calls

Tags: camera, internet

Is there a software pacakge for Pi, which allows to call over Internet with Camera and TV ? Must be super simple for very dummy user.
Plus is, when there is possibility to extend the functionality to full mediacenter when experienced user comes.

Answer (score 1):

Media center is already there: [OpenELEC](http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/Raspberry_Pi). For calling: no, that's a *much* more complicated proposition and there's no "simple" way I'm aware of at the moment.

Comment: ok, less is actually more for me. Unfortunatelly, no luck so far.